# I don't see hints in Netbeans 6.9.1

Tags: java, netbeans

When something is wrong in code, light bulb appears and when i moved over it, a yellow box with some information appears. It also says, Alt-Enter shows hints. This is my problem, i can't see those hints.
I had no problem with hints in version 6.7, but now i don't know what happened.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I hate to say it but: works for me. Please provide some additional information like what OS and JRE you're running.

Comment: I am running Windows 7 and jre 6 update 21.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools->Options menu, then select Editor->Hints tabs and check the checkboxes selections.

Comment: I have already done that before and most of checkboxes are selected (the ones that are by default).

Comment: You may open an issue on http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html
If it is common it will be fixed, and at least answered by NetBeans team.